# What level of reputation do you have to get to, to be able to comment in all posts?

Tags: support

I have a query regarding being able to comment in all posts? Currently my reputation only allows me a privilege of being able to comment in the main forum on certain posts (the level is about 44% for being able to comment on all posts I think, so I presume this only allows me to comment in my own posts?). Can I ask at what level do I need to get to, to be able to comment in all posts? The reason why I ask is that I have been quite open since I have been here that I don't have as strong a background as most users that post here and I have seen a topic that I can contribute to and yet I can't comment. I can answer the question (but can't comment) but I don't feel that the answer would be strong enough to warrant an answer (in the main forum) and it would be more suitable as a comment initially. I'm just wondering what level do I have to get to before I am in a position to contribute (as ironically I feel that it would perhaps add to my reputation).

Thanks for any advice on the matter.

Comment: Have you looked at our FAQ? http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Comment: My apologies - I was looking at the general FAQ and didn't realise that there was one specifically for reputation (which does make sense given the importance of it). Apologies and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can comment on their own posts, it takes 50 points to comment globally.

[This information in the FAQ, under "Reputation"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)